# Java thread enters while condition even if the condition is false

Tags: java, multithreading

I currently try to write an application that sends customers to the shortest queue. Each queue has its own thread. 
In the Queue class I have an instance variable `nrClients` that keeps track of how many clients there are in the queue.

In the run method I have a while condition that keeps the thread running only if `nrClients` is larger than 0, but sometimes it enters that while loop even if `nrClients` is 0, triggering a `NullPointerException` in the code inside that while. I also have a for loop that goes from `0` to `nrClients-1`, but sometimes it enters that loop and gives me an `Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` exception. Here's the code I have written in that class:

```java
public class Queue implements Runnable{
    BlockingQueue<Client> queue;
    private int nrClients;
    private AtomicInteger waitTime;
    private boolean isClosed=true;

    public Queue(){
        nrClients= 0;
        waitTime = new AtomicInteger(0);
        queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Client>();
    }

    public void addClient(Client c){
        nrClients++;
        queue.add(c);
        waitTime.addAndGet(c.getServiceTime());
        c.setWaitTime(waitTime.get());
    }

    private void removeClient(Client c){
        nrClients--;
        queue.remove();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
            while (nrClients>0) {
                isClosed = false;
                Client c = queue.peek();
                try {
                    int mustWait = c.getServiceTime();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mustWait; i++) {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        c.decServiceTime();
                        waitTime.decrementAndGet();
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                removeClient(c);
            }
            if (nrClients == 0)
                isClosed = true;
    }

    public AtomicInteger getWaitTime() {
        return waitTime;
    }

    public String toString(){
        if(nrClients==0){
            return "closed";
        }
        else
        {
            String r="";
            for(int i=0; i<nrClients; i++){
                Client c = (Client) queue.toArray()[i];
                r+="("+c.getID()+","+c.getArrivalTime()+","+c.getServiceTime()+"); ";
            }
            return r;
        }
    }

    public boolean isClosed() {
        return isClosed;
    }
```

I can't seem to find the problem that leads to these exceptions, I would appreciate if you could point out what's wrong. Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** I've tried making nrClients volatile / AtomicInteger, neither fixed the problem. Also, by substituting nrClients with queue.size() I am still getting the index exception in the for loop included in the toString method.

Comment: I've tried with queue.size() but it still runs into exceptions in that for loop, with Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Comment: Be aware that Increment operators aren’t threadsafe.

Answer (score 4):

If some other thread calls `addClient`, the `nrClient` is increased **before** the object `c` is added to the `queue`. If the while loop runs exactly at this time, `nrClient` is 1 but the `queue` is still empty.

You need to `synchronise` the method `addClient` with access to `nrClient` and `queue` (one way this can be done is by implementing a method getNrClient() and then both methods `getNrClient` and `addClient` are `synchronized(lock)` with a common `Object lock = new Object()`).

Better: avoid using nrClient all together. Instead check for queue.peek not being null or use poll.

The problem with queue.size() in the for loop is similar, you call queue.size() and queue.toArray() at different times, hence they may be inconsistent. Instead: Fetch the array outside the for loop and use array.length.

Comment: Wouldn't `queue.size()` be better instead of `nrClient`? I'd prefer using it instead of queue.peek() because I also need it in the for loop inside `toString` method. The problem is, it still gives me an Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 exception inside the `for(int i=0; i<queue.size(); i++)` loop.

Comment: No. Fetch the array outside the for loop and use array.length. (I made an update to my answer).

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are executing `run` in a different thread. As `nrClients` is not `volatile` it needn't be reading any new values. Having said that, I don't like the look of the rest of the code.

Comment: Yes, I am executing this thread in a different thread. I've tried making nrClients volatile / AtomicInteger but neither fixed the problem